# Issue, Iguazio synch Active Directory groups

Tags: active-directory, mlrun

Issue, it is not possible to define which Active Directory groups will be synchronized in Iguazio. I did not see ability to define these groups in IDP (Active Directory) provider setting, see UI content. I am using Iguazio 3.5.1.

[image]

Thanks for help about this setting.

Comment: The "Person filter" value quite clearly shows an LDAP query filter with a `memberOf` clause. Is this filter not resolving to any user accounts?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, it helps to create relevant users but It will create all groups from these users (e.g. ~200 groups). I would like to create only a few group with relation to Iguazio (~10 groups) not all user groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version `Iguazio >= 3.5.3` contains setting for Active Directory 'Group filter' also. See the picture.

[image]

After setting Group filter, only these groups will be synchronized from Active Directory.

The typical setting of Group filter is e.g.

```
(&(objectClass=group)(|(cn=XX.FeatureStore.Admin)(cn=XX.FeatureStore.Dev)(cn=XX.FeatureStore.Support)))
```